# tryng to import a file inside a function,then using the import in another function, getting a unresolve error

Tags: python

Is there a way to import a module inside a function, then use it outside that function? I'm assuming the issue is that the import name is local and not global. I don't know how to fix it.
sample code:

```py
def func1():
    import modshare
    modshare.ken=2
    print("func1")

    func2()

def func2():
    print("func2")
    # Error here modshare undefined 
    modshare.ken = 2

func1()
```

Comment: Importing within functions is not a great practice, is there any reason you don't want to import it globally in the beginning of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, though whether it's a good idea, and what method is best, depends on what you're trying to do. More details would be needed for that.

### 1. Pass as argument

Modules are objects, so you can pass them around.

```
def func1():
    import sys
    func2(sys)

def func2(module):
    print(module)

func1()  # -> <module 'sys' (built-in)>
```

### 2. Global

Module names are variables, so you could use a global declaration, though [globals are generally a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19158339/4518341), so avoid this if you can.

```
def func1():
    global sys
    import sys
    func2()

def func2():
    print(sys)

func1()  # -> <module 'sys' (built-in)>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I think I'm following what you are asking, then maybe this will work. First off, let me start by saying that importing within functions is not a good practice and should be avoided when you can. It makes things messy to maintain. Try returning the modified object (assuming the import is a class or something) from the first function when passing it to the next function (essentially making a copy of it):

```
def func1():
    import modshare as result
    result.ken = 2
    print("func1")
    return result

def func2():
    func2_result = func1()
    func2_result.ken = 5
    print("func2")

func2()
```